# Space between parent and child div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to remove the white space between the parent and child div.

[image]

It seems that this white line is not visible on all devices/browsers. The bug appears mostly on mobile

All sizes are specified in pixels so it doesn't seem to be half a pixel that is causing the bug.

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
}

.child {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That issue doesn't seem to happen on the code snippet you posted. It may be caused by something else?

Comment: As I said it seems that this white line is not visible on all devices/browsers.

Comment: Well, which device is having this issue?

Comment: have you tried using `height: 100%` on the child instead of the identical px value?

Comment: Yeah I tried this is not the problem..

Answer (score 0):

To ensure it absolutely doesn't happen on any device, you could make the height of the child 82px and hide overflow with CSS. I've encountered something like this when the height of parent and child are exactly the same.

Comment: It's a good idea, I already tried to implement it unfortunately it doesn't fix the bug. I hesitate to implement this solution without the hidden overflow. There is an overflow pixel but it's less shocking than the white line.

Comment: Okay. Try to cut the background-color from the .child in CSS and paste in the parent. Fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <style>
    body{
        margin:auto;
    }
    .parent{
      border: 2px solid;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      height:80px;
      padding:;
    }
    
    .child {
      height:80px;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    </style>
    <div class="parent">
          <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I still see the bug with your code